# Naming convention for packages and projects

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

There was a discussion about that here in SO but I still have a question about that topic, though. So, a simple question: what is a naming convention for projects in Scala? Is it "my_new_project", "myNewProject", "my-new-project", "MyNewProject" or "mynewproject"? And the same question for packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific naming convention for projects in Scala, but usually the Java convention is used, so:
- thisIsAVariable (all but first word initial letter uppercase aka camelCase)
- ThisIsAClass (all initial letters uppercase aka PascalCase)
- com.example.www (reversed url for packages)

I've seen both camelCase and PascalCase for naming projects in Java, but I prefer PascalCase!

Answer (score 7):

Packages follow `com.mycompany.myproject` reversed-URL style. There is no naming convention for project names. Many people prefer all lower case with hyphenation like `scala-foo`. I prefer capitalised camel-case like `ScalaFoo`. It's a matter of taste. I have not seen `scalaFoo` as a project name convention, also underscore is not used (I think that's C or Python style?)

---

Like in the earlier days of Java, where almost every project begins with a `J`, there are a lot of projects beginning with `scala`. While I think this makes sense for porting existing libraries, I came to think that you should probably not call your project `ScalaFoo` or `ScFoo` but just `Foo` unless there is a specific reason to highlight the fact it's written in Scala.

---

You may take a look [at the community libraries wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries) to sense the taste for project names.

Comment: what about com.superlongpcompanyname.myproject?

Answer (score 1):

For projects, I have seen many people use `my-new-project` or `MyNewProject` frequently. I personally prefer `MyNewProject`. I have researched your question a lot and haven't found any set conventions for project names. I do believe on GitHub a lot of repositories use `my-new-project` and almost appears like it's their own convention for repository names.

For packages, the convention is to either use a company domain address or personal domain address with all lowercase letters in reverse order style: `com.company.packagename`.

Hope that helps!

Brady